# Add share_dialog box in a post message

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have a problem when I post a message on my profil, I create an action link nammed "share" which create a shared_dialog box. However it doesn't work... When I click on my "share" link it's running again and again and then I press F5 key to refresh I got my dialog box in a page insted of an iframe ...
Is there anybody to help me ?
Thanks by advance.

```
    var client = new FacebookClient("my_access_token");
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
    parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
    parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
    parameters.name = "Article Title";
    parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
    parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
    var actions = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
            actions["name"] = "share";
            actions["link"] = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?"
                + "app_id=" + settings.AppId
                + "&display=" + "iframe"
                + "&redirect_uri=" + "http://www.exemple.com/test/"
                + "&link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/"
                + "&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg"
                + "&name=Ma%20Dialog%20Box"
                + "&message=Hey"
                + "&description=Test";

parameters.actions = actions
    parameters.privacy = new {
        value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
    };
    parameters.targeting = new {
        countries = "US",
        regions = "6,53",
        locales = "6",
    };
    dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally find another solution which did the same thing

Comment: .... and why don't you share that solution ?